# Erro com array php

Tags: php

Estou montando um array, mas parece que estou fazendo errado, pois não funciona corretamente.

```
$checklisIni = array(
    $_POST['checklistIni0']     =>  $_POST['checklistNome0'],
    $_POST['checklistIni1']     =>  $_POST['checklistNome1'],
    $_POST['checklistIni2']     =>  $_POST['checklistNome2'],
    $_POST['checklistIni3']     =>  $_POST['checklistNome3'],
    $_POST['checklistIni4']     =>  $_POST['checklistNome4'],
    $_POST['checklistIni5']     =>  $_POST['checklistNome5'],
    $_POST['checklistIni6']     =>  $_POST['checklistNome6'],
    $_POST['checklistIni7']     =>  $_POST['checklistNome7'],
    $_POST['checklistIni8']     =>  $_POST['checklistNome8'],
    $_POST['checklistIni9']     =>  $_POST['checklistNome9'],
    $_POST['checklistIni10']    =>  $_POST['checklistNome10'],
    $_POST['checklistIni11']    =>  $_POST['checklistNome11'],
    $_POST['checklistIni12']    =>  $_POST['checklistNome12'],
    $_POST['checklistIni13']    =>  $_POST['checklistNome13'],
    $_POST['checklistIni14']    =>  $_POST['checklistNome14'],
    $_POST['checklistIni15']    =>  $_POST['checklistNome15']
);

print_r($checklisIni);


exit();
```

Retorno do `$checklistIni`:

> Array ( [tem] => Retrovisor interno )

Deveria ter mais valores, pois dando um `print_r($_POST);` aparece todos esses valores:

```
[checklistNome0] => Documento
[checklistIni0] => tem
[checklistNome1] => Manual
[checklistIni1] => tem
[checklistNome2] => Vidro eletrico
[checklistIni2] => tem
[checklistNome3] => Radio/CD
[checklistIni3] => tem
[checklistNome4] => Comando retro. inter
[checklistIni4] => tem
[checklistNome5] => Arcondicionado
[checklistIni5] => tem
[checklistNome6] => Travas portas
[checklistIni6] => tem
[checklistNome7] => Antena
[checklistIni7] => tem
[checklistNome8] => Chave reserva
[checklistIni8] => tem
[checklistNome9] => Tapetes
[checklistIni9] => tem
[checklistNome10] => Revest. interno
[checklistIni10] => tem
[checklistNome11] => Bancos
[checklistIni11] => tem
[checklistNome12] => Macaco
[checklistIni12] => tem
[checklistNome13] => Chave de rodas
[checklistIni13] => tem
[checklistNome14] => Triangulo
[checklistIni14] => tem
[checklistNome15] => Retrovisor interno
[checklistIni15] => tem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Seu código está fazendo exatamente como o programado. Você está criando um índice no array e atribuindo um valor correto, entretanto todos os índices tem o mesmo nome. No seu caso, esse nome é o `tem`. Uma solução mais simples para o seu problema é inverter as coisas na criação de seu array. Veja:

```php
$checklisIni = array(
    $_POST['checklistNome0'] => $_POST['checklistIni0'],
    $_POST['checklistNome1'] => $_POST['checklistIni1'],
    $_POST['checklistNome2'] => $_POST['checklistIni2'],
    $_POST['checklistNome3'] => $_POST['checklistIni3'],
    $_POST['checklistNome4'] => $_POST['checklistIni4'],
    $_POST['checklistNome5'] => $_POST['checklistIni5'],
    $_POST['checklistNome6'] => $_POST['checklistIni6'],
    $_POST['checklistNome7'] => $_POST['checklistIni7'],
    $_POST['checklistNome8'] => $_POST['checklistIni8'],
    $_POST['checklistNome9'] => $_POST['checklistIni9'],
    $_POST['checklistNome10'] => $_POST['checklistIni10'],
    $_POST['checklistNome11'] => $_POST['checklistIni11'],
    $_POST['checklistNome12'] => $_POST['checklistIni12'],
    $_POST['checklistNome13'] => $_POST['checklistIni13'],
    $_POST['checklistNome14'] => $_POST['checklistIni14'],
    $_POST['checklistNome15'] => $_POST['checklistIni15']
);
```

Retorno do `$checklisIni`:

```
Array(
    [Documento] => tem
    [Manual] => tem
    [Vidro eletrico] => tem
    [Radio/CD] => tem
    [Comando retro. inter] => tem
    [Arcondicionado] => tem
    [Travas portas] => tem
    [Antena] => tem
    [Chave reserva] => tem
    [Tapetes] => tem
    [Revest. interno] => tem
    [Bancos] => tem
    [Macaco] => tem
    [Chave de rodas] => tem
    [Triangulo] => tem
    [Retrovisor interno] => tem
)
```

Uma dica que eu dou, ao invés de enviar 32 posts, oque pode ficar um pouco puxado para o servidor, que tal enviar um post único contendo um array ou um objeto? Você pode enviar isso no formato JSON. Isso vai deixar suas requisições mais leve e simples!
Espero ter ajudado, abraço!

Comment: Valeu Lucas! Muito obrigado.

Comment: Como seria para enviar via JSON?

Comment: Se você estiver enviando esses posts de um javascript, por exemplo, basta dar um `JSON.stringify()` em seu array, e enviar um único post (por exemplo com o name data). Então, no seu php basta você passar isso para array novamente, utilizando o `json_decode`. Exemplo: `$array = json_decode($_POST["data"])`.